# Returning null from a function that returns a pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers, null, return

I'm writing a program that involves a function that will take 2 strings as input . The function should return a pointer to the occurrence of str2 in str1 if it exists , if not it has to return NULL .The function should basically return str2 if it was found in str1 . The code works but i cant figure out how to return NULL from the function if newstring has no elements. Any guidance on how to return NULL if the newstring wasn't assigned would be appreciated,  Thanks!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
int lenstr(T str1)      // Function that finds length of a string , instead of using the strlen or sizeof functions.
                        // this function will work for all data types and not just char.
{
    int count = 0;
    while(str1[count] != '\0')
    {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
char* mystrstr(char *str1 , const char* str2)
{
    int len1 = lenstr(str1);
    int len2 = lenstr(str2);
    char *newstring = new char[len2];
    int i = 0;
        for (int j = 0;j<len1;j++)
        {
            if(str1[j] == str2[i])
            {
                newstring[i] = str1[j];
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
            i = 0;
            }
        }
        return newstring;
}
void main()
{
    char str1[28] = {"this is a test program"};
    char str2[15] = {"tes"};
    int len2 = lenstr(str2);
    char* returnstring;
    returnstring = mystrstr(str1,str2);
    for(int i = 0;i<len2;i++)
    {
    cout<<returnstring[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;

    delete returnstring;

}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `void main()` please use one of the defined entry points.

Comment: Not sure I understand but: 1.) What exactly is wrong with `return NULL;`? 2.) Why not use `nullptr` if you use C++11? 3.) Why not use `std::string`? 4.) `void main` is not valid C++.

Comment: Pass `"tetex"` as the first string and `"tex"` as the second.  Your code fails.  In fact, your code should not call `new` -- you almost certainly are supposed to return a pointer into the first string where the substring starts.  All of these are fundamental problems with your code that are independent of your question.

Comment: @Yakk why isn't it supposed to call new? i'm defining the size of newstring inside the function so that it's of the same size as str2 and will have the output that i return at the end.

Comment: @kareem because "if a is substring of b, return a copy of a" is a very silly function.  And the return value is not 'the copy of a within b' as you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try initializing newstr with all 0's, like so:

```
char *newstring = new char[len2];

for (int i = 0; i < len2; i++) {
    newstring[i] = '0';
}
```

(newstr should by default be initialized with 0s, but I'm not quite sure on this, so I just posted that loop since I'm not 100% on that)

And then, at the end of your loop, if newstring still contains 0 at the first index, return 
`nullptr`.

Answer (score 1):

Your variant of strstr doesn't return  a pointer to the occurance of str2 in str1. It just takes as many letters from the str1, that are in str2 and returns pointer to new string.
This is what you need if your question is right:

```
char* mystrstr(char *str1 , char* str2)
{
    int len1 = lenstr(str1);
    int len2 = lenstr(str2);
    char *ptr1, *ptr2;
    char *result;

    for(ptr1 = str1, ptr2 = str2; *ptr1; ptr1++)
    {
        if(*ptr2 == 0)
            break;
        if(*ptr1 == *str2)
            result = ptr1;
        if(*ptr1 == *ptr2)
        {
            ptr2++;
        }
        else
        {
            ptr2 = str2;
            result = NULL;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
int main()
{
    char str1[28] = {"this is a test program"};
    char str2[15] = {"tes"};
    int len2 = lenstr(str2);
    char* returnstring;
    returnstring = mystrstr(str1,str2);
    if(returnstring != NULL)
    {
        cout << returnstring;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "returnstring is NULL" << endl;
    }
    delete returnstring;
}
```